# '403 forbidden error' after xampp installation

Tags: apache2, xampp, apache2.4

I just installed Xampp 5.6.21 (Apache 2.4.18)

I moved the installation from `/opt/lampp` to `/home/peter/project/xampp` and created a symlink from `/opt/lampp` to the new destination.

I can start the server:

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.21-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
```

If I enter `http://localhost/xampp` in the browser I get an `403 forbidden` error. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Try doing `sudo chmod -R 777 /home/peter/project/xampp` to set the permission so that everyone can read / write, does that fix it ?

Comment: @JonasCz you should also mention that it is not advisable to do this normally, I would rather suggest installing apache and properly setting it up as a LAMP stack.

Comment: @JonasCz I did that. It's still forbidden.

Comment: @Videonauth I need multiple Apache installations with different config to simulate different production servers, that's why I went with Xampp.

Comment: when you set this up did you use a self created server config file or did you use a default one from the install?

Comment: @JohnOrion I haven't changed anything yet. It's a fresh install.

Comment: have you gone into the default web directory to see what is in there .. see if you have an index.html or something in there and that it has the 777 permissions you set .. see if there is a .htaccess file in there and make sure that it isn't for some reason set to deny access.

Comment: There is an `index.php` in `xampp/htdocs/` It's all 777.  I can't find a .htaccess anywhere in `xampp/`

Comment: ok who is the owner and group of xampp ... I would change it to www-data:www-data for the directories dealing with this server which I'm assuming is `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/peter/project/xampp` This probably won't help since you have it at 777 so www-data should have access but this is how it should be and since you copied it .. they are probably set to your login name or root. I'm not sure about this setup ... are you sure that the default config is set to follow symlinks.. you may need to check that

Comment: I used `rsync -aAXog` to copy `/opt/lampp` so owners and permissions remained the the same (root:root mostly). Regarding symlinks, this line in `httpd.conf` is enabled by defaulf: `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes`. I just found out that if I just install xampp and leave it at `/opt/lampp` it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was quite simple to solve. The project dir above the xampp dir had permissions of 700. After changing it to 755 everything worked fine.